# Java Encryption: What seed to use in my AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding scenario

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, block-cipher, secure-random

I am building an app that will use AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding method to encrypt user's data on their device, and security is of high importance. I want to prevent brute force attack in case someone gets hold of the database.

Each row in the table has an associated title. I am not sure what to use as the seed. I can do one of the following:

1. Hard code my own seed in the source, but I believe this can be read if someone decompiles my app
2. Use the title entered by the user as the seed
3. Use a concatenation of my own seed as well as the entered title

Unless there are other ways, in all the above scenarios, I can visualise someone figuring out the seed. Will this be useful to them in being able to brute force the encrypted data? Of course in all the above scenarios, I also include the User's password as a part of the key.

How can I make it more difficult for a potential hacker?

**Edit** (Re-Edited)

Based on the replies below and my research and thought process. I think I can do the following.

1. Have the user enter a password, but not store it in the database
2. Before storing the sensitive data, they have to enter a Label to identify it. I will store this as clear text in the database and use it as a salt
3. I will use the user's password and Label with PBKDF2 to generate a key, but will not store it
4. I will use the generated key from #3 to encrypt the sensitive data
5. To decrypt, I will again generate the key based off the user's password and row label and will use it to decrypt the sensitive data

Does this sound right? Will a hacker be able to deduce anything if they get hold of the database with the two columns - label clear text, and encrypted data?

**Edit 2**

I am planning to build an Android App to be specific and the following links were bang on what I needed.

https://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html?m=1

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html?m=1

Comment: Padding is not encryption...what exactly is your encryption method/library

Comment: What do you mean by seed?

Comment: @LukePark I meant the private key that is used to encrypt/decrypt. I convert that into bytes and pass it to... SecureRandom.setSeed(byte[] seed)

Comment: I feel like you could benefit from some further research into crypto topics.  Client side only encryption should do something similar to the following: User password is used to generate an AES key and a HMAC key.  PBKDF2 with SHA512 is good for this.  Generate a random IV.  Use AES key for symmetric encryption and use an HMAC (HMAC-SHA256 is good) to authenticate the ciphertext and IV.  The HMAC is unnecessary if you are using GCM mode or some other authenticated mode.

Comment: @LukePark Please provide a sample code or online tutorial that implements your suggestion. I am not able to completely get my head around what you mean.

Comment: You need to research this yourself.  If you can't implement/understand on your owe, hire a security consultant.  Security isn't something that you "learn as you go".

Comment: @LukePark Can you see my edits to the original question above and share your thoughts?

Comment: Never ever use `SecureRandom#setSeed(byte[] seed)` and expect to get the same output from `SecureRandom#nextBytes` across multiple runs of your application and across different JVM's. If seed is a password and the output is supposed to be short, use PBKDF2. If seed is a password and the output is supposed to be long, use PBKDF2 and then [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF). If the seed is a key and the output is supposed to be short, use a hash function like SHA-256. If the seed is a key and the output is supposed to be long, use HKDF. Never use the word *"seed"* to describe a *key*.

Comment: @ShahidThaika Please see my answer below regarding your edits.  For the most part your understanding is correct, you just missed the HMAC.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that, whenever someone decompiles your application, the method of generating your key is trivially known. Therefore, if all of the input data to that key generation is known, generating the key is trivial.

Because of that, you might want to provide the user with the possibility to enter a passphrase that will be used with the AES encryption. Make sure that you use a system such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) in order to make it difficult to brute force the passphrase.

If your database is not stored on the user's device, but rather externally, then you might get away with generating and storing a [secure random key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) on the device, and encrypting the data before it actually gets stored in the central database.

Comment: Here's what I thought of doing. I will ask user for a password and encrypt my own secret password (Eg: MySecretKey) with it in the database. When the user opens the app next, it will ask for password and check whether my above encrypted value gets decrypted to "MySecretKey" using the input password. If it does, then I will use that key to further encrypt other data that needs encryption. Is PBKDF2 stronger than AES-256 bit? The wiki seems to say that brute forcing is pretty cheap.

Comment: @ShahidThaika PBKDF is a hash function which is (should be) performance expensive and generates a usable key for AES encryption from a user-provided (weaker) password.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment and your edits, a possible solution boils down to this (I'm not really a Java programmer, but the below pseudo-code should be clear):

```
aesKey <- PBKDF2-SHA512(userPassword)[:32]
hmacKey <- PBKDF2-SHA512(userPassword)[32:] // PBKDF2-SHA512 has a natural 64 byte output

iv <- CSPRNG(16) // 16 byte IV for AES from a CSPRNG
ciphertext <- AES256CBC(plainText, aesKey, iv) // Use PKCS5Padding

result <- iv + ciphertext // Prepend the IV.
result <- HMAC-SHA256(result, hmacKey) + result
// Prepend the HMAC of the IV and ciphertext using the hmacKey.  Always encrypt THEN mac.
```

A couple of important notes:

- You should always include the IV in the HMAC, e.g. don't HMAC just the ciphertext.
- The selection of SHA512 and SHA256 is important.  Since SHA512 has a natural output of 64 bytes, it is perfect for deriving two 32 byte keys using PBKDF2.  If you adjust this algorithm, then you'll be using more than just the final PBKDF2 iteration to generate the next lot of bytes, which isn't beneficial.
- The salt that you use for PBKDF2 isn't actually that important.  You could randomly generate this and store it alongside the ciphertext, however, a static salt for PBKDF2 would be fine in this instance.